# Google Ads Language Targeting Script

Tags: google-apps-script

is there actually a way to change Google Ads campaigns 'Language targeting' via a Google Ads script?

I've created a few scripts in the past but looking at the documentation i can't seem to find a way of actually adding/editing location targeting.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_language

Looking here i see 'remove' as an option but not the ability to add a location target or edit a current one.

Am i missing something?

Many thanks
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add a language target to a campaign? If that is the case then the method you are looking for is on the campaign object. Here's [the link](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_campaign#addLocation_1).

Your code would look something like:

```
var locationId = 1000; // ID for English
var campaigns = AdsApp.campaigns().get();
var campaign1 = campaigns.next();
campaign1.addLocation(locationId);
```

You can find the list of location IDs [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats).